# Sequence of Activity after autostart on Boot of application

Tags: android, android-activity

here we show you my problem; 
I am developing an android application and I set that an activity will start automatically after power-up or reboot of the device. (and this work well).

But my real problem is that I want to execute a piece of code attached to a menu item placed in the activity that start automatically.

How can I run a automatic-click on a menu item?

Comment: Why can't you just attach the desired code directly into the boot activity itself? Why do you need to use a click to launch the code?

Comment: cause a code of connection is declarated in a inner class , in a boolean method for click on item menu..this is a problem

Comment: Extract the code into a separate method that is unrelated to and independent from the menu item click. Then call it from both menu item click and `onCreate()` method in your `Activity`. This is called "refactoring".